# Picasso в Android

Tags: java, android, picasso

Добрый вечер.Пишу приложение для обоев на телефон.Как способ загрузки их,требуется использовать Picasso.Вопрос насчет серверной части:Picasso может загружать изображения только с url,как это реализовать(хранение изображений с url)нужно арендовать хостинг,или есть другие варианты решения этой проблемы?